# Is TextBox string clearing in code behind against MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, textbox

I am writing small project to learn MVVM WPF. In the project I am opening with a button dialog window with form to fill up. The form has 2 `TextBoxes`, that I want to have them empty every time the dialog window is opened again.

[image]

In StackOverflow is a lot of examples where TextBox is binded to methods that they are cleaning TextBox with `.Clear();` or `string.Empty;` or `.Text=""`; etc.

The problem is, that my TextBoxes are already `MultiBinded` to the converter method used with the form.

```
       <local:CustomContentDialogBox.CommandParameter>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource newPerson}">
                <Binding ElementName="tbID" Path="Text"/>
                <Binding ElementName="tbFirstName" Path="Text"/>
                <Binding ElementName="tbSecondName" Path="Text"/>
                <Binding ElementName="cbHeight" Path="Text" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </local:CustomContentDialogBox.CommandParameter>
```

As far as I experienced, I was not able to bind it from the texbox by itself again like that:

```
       <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                x:Name="tbFirstName"
                FontSize="20" 
                Margin="10,0,0,0" 
                Background="#F5F5F5" 
                TextAlignment="Left"
                Text="{Binding ClearMyBoxPlease}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Width="150"/>
```

After all day research I figured out, that I can just add to the button in dialog window Click="Button_Click" and clean text boxes in code behind.

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Margin="5,5,5,5"
                Height="30" Width="80"
                FontSize="20"
                Background="#ccffe1"
                Content="Add"
                Click="Button_Click"
                local:CustomContentDialogBox.CustomContentDialogResult="True">
                </Button>
```

Code behind, where I want clean up only 2 text boxes:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tbFirstName.Text = "";
            tbSecondName.Text = "";
        }
```

For your reference, my converter class, that takes TextBoxes from MultiBinding:

```
public class PersonConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        HeightListToString pzts = new HeightListToString();
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string id = (string)values[0];
            string firstName = (string)values[1];
            string secondName = (string)values[2];
            Model.HeightList heightList = (Model.HeightList)pzts.ConvertBack(
            values[3], typeof(Model.HeightList), null, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            return new ViewModel.PersonsList(id, firstName, secondName, heightList);
        }
        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Also I was trying to use `ICommand` in my ViewModel class and bind it with TextBox. Even if the syntax is wrong, the program was not walking through break points on it:

```
private ICommand clearMyBoxPlease;

        public ICommand ClearMyBoxPlease
        {
            get
            {
                clearMyBoxPlease = new RelayCommand(
                    argument =>
                    {
                        TextBox tb = (TextBox)argument;
                        tb.Clear();
                    }
                    );
                return clearMyBoxPlease;
            }
        }
```

My point is, that it is only one code behind that gave me proper effect. The question, is my code against MVVM pattern theory? If yes, what solution should I use? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I just tryed:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                         x:Name="tbFirstName"

                   FontSize="20" 
                   Margin="10,0,0,0" 
                   Background="#F5F5F5" 
                   TextAlignment="Left"  
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Width="150">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotLost">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ClearMyTextPlease}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </TextBox>
```

with command:

```
public ICommand ClearMyTextPlease 
        {
            get
            {
                if (clearMyTextPlease == null)
                    clearMyTextPlease = new RelayCommand(
                        argument =>
                        {
                            TextBox tb = (TextBox)argument;
                            tb.Text = string.Empty;
                        }
                        );
                return clearMyTextPlease;
            }
        }
```

It still does not go through breakpoints on `ClearMyTextPlease`.

Comment: The VM should handle the button click and clear the model, which would reflect in the bindings and clear the textbox. You shouldn't (really, but it happens) have code-behind on the views.

Comment: If you are binding to TextBoxes you shouldn't clear them by setting the `TextBox.Text`. Clearing the value it is bound to should automatically clear the text. If you manually set the `TextBox.Text` value, you will break the binding.

Comment: MVVM does provide an easy mechanism for clearing UI elements from the VM without having to do so in code behind.  Contrary to an above comment, MVVM does not mean never use code-behind.  There are aspects of WPF apps that require it that go beyond MVVM

Comment: @MickyD what mechanism you mean?

Comment: WPF Binding....

Comment: @MickyD it did not work. Please see my update on the question.

Comment: @Tronald you was right. Currently I used `GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus"` and it makes me happy, but still I have to write method in code behind. Anyway, I was reading, that it is no big problem to manage UI elements from code behind.

Comment: MVVM is one of the solutions for "Separation of concerns". It's main goal to separate code for UI and Business logic. So if your code in "code behind" is only view-related - it is ok to have it there.

Comment: One of the MVVM restrictions is that `ViewModel` should know nothing about `View` - that mean you shouldn't use view controls (`TextBox`) in the ViewModel.

Comment: @Fabio that case in what layer I am supposed to clear text in my TextBoxes? Some posts in StackOverflow people were suggesting, to clear TextBox from ViewModel using binding.

Comment: @Przemyslaw.Pszemek - if you clear it in the viewmodel through bounded property - then you will have possibility to write automated tests for the viewmodel where clearing of the value can be tested, or you will have possibility to re-use same viewmodel for another view with similar behaviour. If you don't care about previous possibilities - then you can do it in code-behind, but only in case where clearing will not involve some parts of business logic of your application

Comment: @Fabio _"It's main goal to separate code for UI and Business logic"_ - no it doesn't.

Comment: @MickyD, _no it doesn't_ say nothing - can you suggest your version, I will be glad to remove my comment.

Comment: @Fabio That's fine.  I like to delegate the work out to "services" and do it there. Now by services I just means some _proxy/facade_ class the VM calls when business logic needs to be carried out.  Such classes can be anywhere in your VS solution but typically outside MVVM land.  So a typical call sequence could start in the code-behind-handler for `ICommand` `OnExecute` (where you might be `await`ing in the UI context) ---> VM --->  service.DoSomething(Model model).  Starting in the code-behind is purely optional

Comment: @MickyD - by "UI" and "Business logic" I meant exactly same approach. Where "UI" is a view, and "Business logic" is your service. And viewmodel is implementation detail of MVVM which glue UI and business logic together without coupling UI t with Business logic ;)

Comment: @Fabio Agreed good sir :)

Comment: By the way, guys. Still I have a problem. My `Text="{Binding ClearText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"` binding to the ICommand, that is processing method making `blank = new ModelTextClear("");` still does not work. Debug does not go through the breakpoints on the command. Is it possible, that it is because `TextBox` is already in `MultiBinding` for its `Text` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just for the future reference. I solved my problem with clearing TextBoxes in my dialog window from VM.

Still I was not able to bind my Text to the property, probably I did something wrong, but I used VisualTreeHelper and called the method before closing the window.

Method:

```
static public void TraverseVisualTree(Visual myMainWindow)
    {
        int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(myMainWindow);
        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            var visualChild = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myMainWindow, i);
            if (visualChild is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox tb = (TextBox)visualChild;
                tb.Clear();
            }
            TraverseVisualTree(visualChild);
        }
    }
```

Calling in dialg window class in VM:

```
public CustomContentDialogBox()
    {
        execute =
        o => //parametr "o" wyrażenia lambda
        {
            if (window == null)
            {
                window = new Window();

                window.Width = WindowWidth;
                window.Height = WindowHeight;
                if (Caption != null) window.Title = Caption;
                window.Content = WindowContent;
                //(some logic)
                TraverseVisualTree(window); 
                window = null;
            }
        };
    }
```